# Printing out diary entries from Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Just had a quick question about an Android diary app I have. I'm trying to implement a feature where the user clicks on a "Show Entries" button on the app, and it displays all diary entries that have previously been inserted into the database. '

First the user log into the app, and the username/password are stored in the database. From there, the user can click on a "Create Entry" button to actually enter in a date/diary entry. Unfortunately, this is where the app is getting hung up, and it's not actually inserting the date and diary entry into the database.

Specifically, it's getting hung up at the DataBaseHelper class in diaryEntry() where it attempts to enter the values into the table with

```
long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

result returns a 2, so the conditional below that call returns true, but neither of the Strings are entered into COL_4 & COL_5 in the database. I've been tearing my hair out trying to catch what I'm missing, but I'm not seeing it. Could I borrow a big brain or two to provide a few pointers? Thanks!

The main diary page

```
public class DiaryMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button showEntries;
    private DataBaseHelper myDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary_main);

        showEntries = findViewById(R.id.showDiaryEntriesBtn);
        myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    }

    public void createEntryOnClick(View view) {
        Intent entryClick = new Intent(this, DiaryEntry.class);
        startActivity(entryClick);
    }

    public void showEntriesOnClick() {

        showEntries.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor res = myDB.getData();

                if (res.getCount() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(DiaryMain.this, "No entries", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                while (res.moveToNext()) {
                    buffer.append("Date: " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                    //buffer.append("Entry: " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), buffer.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
            }
        });
    }
```

The diary entry intent

```
public class DiaryEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText date, diaryEntry;
    Button createBtn;
    private DataBaseHelper myDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary_entry);

        date = findViewById(R.id.dateField);
        diaryEntry = findViewById(R.id.entryField);
        createBtn = findViewById(R.id.diaryEntryBtn);

        myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        createEntry();
    }

    private void createEntry() {
        createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String passDate = date.getText().toString();
                String passEntry = diaryEntry.getText().toString();

                boolean var = myDB.diaryEntry(passDate, passEntry);

                if (var){
                    Toast.makeText(DiaryEntry.this, "Entry posted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DiaryEntry.this, "Posting error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

And the database helper

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "USER_RECORD";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "USER_DATA";
    private static final String COL_1 = "ID ";
    private static final String COL_2 = "USERNAME";
    private static final String COL_3 = "PASSWORD";
    private static final String COL_4 = "DATE";
    private static final String COL_5 = "ENTRY";

    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, DATE TEXT, ENTRY TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean registerUser(String username, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COL_2, username);
        values.put(COL_3, password);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean diaryEntry(String date, String diaryText) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COL_4, date);
        values.put(COL_5, diaryText);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
             return true;
        }

    }

    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER_DATA", null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Edit: reading the docs, it appears db.insert() inserts rows into the database, so would I be on the right track in that I'd need to create a separate table to insert the date/diary entry pair into?

Comment: Does the app crash?

Comment: No, it just returns to that main diary intent. Debugging it, I can see that it's collecting the entries as strings and storing the local variables, but it's just not kicking them over to the SQLite table. I...think...I might need two separate tables in the database, as it might be trying to insert a row into a table whose first row is already populated by the username/password combo.

Answer (score 1):

`dairyEntry` will insert data with the username and password rows as nulls. However. when you ask *so would I be on the right track in that I'd need to create a separate table to insert the date/diary entry pair into?* then yes.

That is you only need to have a single row per user (date and entry don't need to be in the USER_DATA table) as every entry will have the data repeated.

What I would suggest is the USER_DATA table being built using :-

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)");
```

- AUTOINCREMENT removed as there is no need for it an it is inefficient.
- DATE and ENTRY columns removed.

You would then have a second table with 3 columns. DATE and ENTRY and an INTEGER column that is for referencing the ID of the User (which is NOT the PRIMARY key). It wont hurt to also have an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column (probably not named ID) as it exists anyway (just it's typically hidden).

As an example you could have

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  diary_entry (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, entry TEXT, user_map INTEGER REFERENCES USER_DATA(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

- REFERENCES defines a Foreign Key (basically a rule that says the the user_map column MUST be the id of an existing user)
- ON DELETE CASCADE will delete all rows should the user be deleted (i.e. it cascades the deletion so that there are no orphaned dairy_entry rows)
- On UPDATE will pass any updates made to the user's id (not very likely).

So when inserting an entry you would have a slightly different `diaryEntry` method :-

```
public boolean diaryEntry(long userid, String date, String diaryText) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COL_4, date);
    values.put(COL_5, diaryText);
    values.put("user_map",userid);

    return (db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values) > 0)
    }
}
```

`getAll` would probably then be based upon a query like :-

```
"SELECT diary_entry.*, USER_DATA.USERNAME, USER_DATA.PASSWORD FROM diary_entry JOIN USER_DATA ON diary_entry.user_map = USER_DATA.id;"
```

- note that the cursor will contain columns :-

  - id (the id of the diary_entry row)
  - date
  - entry
  - user_map (same as the id of the user)
  - USERNAME
  - PASSWORD

***The above code hasn't been compiled, run or tested, so it may contains some typos, it is intended as in principle code***

**Working Example/Demo**

The following puts the above into practice (i.e. the DatabaseHelper code) by adding some test data (2 user's and 5 Diary Entries) and displaying the Diary Entries in a ListView, which includes handling of clicking on a List Item in which case it Toast's some info regrading the entry (the diary entry's id and the user's name).

First **DatabaseHelper** :-

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /*
        Can be useful to have names available elsewhere (e.g. some are used in MainActivity)
     */
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "USER_RECORD";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USER_DATA";
    public static final String ENTRY_TABLE_NAME = "diary_entry";
    //public static final String COL_1 = "ID "; /* Cursor Adapters MUST HAVE _id column so replaced by next line */
    public static final String COL_1 = BaseColumns._ID; /* Cursor Adapter expects _id column name */
    public static final String COL_2 = "USERNAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String COL_4 = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_5 = "ENTRY";
    public static final String COl_6 = "user_map";

    private SQLiteDatabase db; // saves having to use getWritableDatabase all the time */

    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Forces an open of the database
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_2 + " TEXT," +
                COL_3 + " TEXT" +
                ")"
        );
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_4 + " TEXT, " +
                COL_5 + " TEXT, " +
                COl_6 + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + /* Included for ListView */
                COL_1 +
                ") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE " +
                ")"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME); /* ADDED */
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean registerUser(String username, String password) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // no need now
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_2, username);
        values.put(COL_3, password);
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values) > 0;
        /* Simpler return used
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
         */
    }

    /*
        This version returns the id of the inserted user (can be useful)

     */
    public long otherReqisterUser(String userName, String password) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_2,userName);
        values.put(COL_3,password);
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }

    public boolean diaryEntry(Long userid, String date, String diaryText) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // not needed now
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COl_6,userid);
        values.put(COL_4, date);
        values.put(COL_5, diaryText);
        return db.insert(ENTRY_TABLE_NAME, null, values) > 0;
    }

    /*
    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER_DATA", null);
        return cursor;
    }
     */

    public Cursor getData() {
        /* rather than rawQuery query convenience method is recommended
           However, this one is a little complex now due to Join
         */

        /* The following is the equivalent of :-
            SELECT diary_entry.*, USER_DATA.USERNAME, USER_DATA.PASSWORD
            FROM diary_entry
            JOIN USER_DATA ON diary_entry.user_map = USER_DATA.id
            ORDER BY USER_DATA._id ASC, diary_entry.date
            ;
         */
        return db.query(
                /* Although doco says this arg is table it is actually the FROM clause so JOIN's go here*/
                ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + " JOIN " + TABLE_NAME + " ON " + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + "." + COl_6 + "=" + TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_1,
                /* The columns as a String[] */
                new String[]{ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + ".*",TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_2, TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_3},
                /* no WHERE clause, no bound parameters (?), no GROUP BY clause, no HAVING clause*/
                null,null,null,null,
                /* However ORDER BY clause by user then by date */
                TABLE_NAME+"."+COL_1+" ASC," + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_4 + " ASC"
                );
    }
}
```

And **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper db;
    Cursor csr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = this.findViewById(R.id.diaryentries); /* List View from layout */
        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        /* Add data if none exists */
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db.getWritableDatabase(),DataBaseHelper.TABLE_NAME)< 1) {
            /* Add some testing users */
            long fredsId = db.otherReqisterUser("FRED", "password");
            long marysId = db.otherReqisterUser("MARY", "password");
            /* Add some diary entries */
            db.diaryEntry(fredsId, "2021-01-01", "Got up (Fred)");
            db.diaryEntry(marysId, "2021-01-01", "Got up (Mary)");
            db.diaryEntry(fredsId, "2021-01-02", "Went to work (Fred)");
            db.diaryEntry(marysId, "2021-02-02", "Was sick.(Mary)");
            db.diaryEntry(fredsId,"1999-01-01","Ooosps wasn't around!!!!");
        }

        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr = db.getData());
        setupOrRefreshListView(); // setup the ListView

    }

    private void setupOrRefreshListView() {
        csr = db.getData();
        if (sca == null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,csr,
                    new String[]{
                            DataBaseHelper.COL_4,
                            DataBaseHelper.COL_5
                    },
                    new int[]{
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            android.R.id.text2
                    },
                    0
            );
            lv.setAdapter(sca);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                            "You clicked on Diary Entry id = " + String.valueOf(l) +
                                    " for " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COL_2)),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(csr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(!csr.isClosed()) {
            csr.close();
        }
    }
}
```

- Hopefully the comments explain things.

**Results**

When run the App looks like :-

[image]

Click on an Entry (Fred Got Up was clicked) and :-

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect, that's exactly what I needed to read. I'll give that a shot in the morning, as my head is fried. Thanks for the great advice!

Comment: @ZapRowsdower working on an example/demo using the above, so the code will be checked. Will update the answer shortly.

Comment: I had fooled around with it once more shortly after your previous answer, and had implemented the second table, but still it was not pushing the text to the second table. I'll try implementing those field changes to see if I can shake this thing into working correctly. Also, much thanks for paring down that getData() function; I was trying to get it to just pull everything, but with our comments, I see how the flow of it is supposed to work now. As a side note, is there a way to click on an entry to edit the content? At any rate, absolute gold my friend, thanks again!!

Comment: @ZapRowsdower added another answer, this implements Click to Edit an Entry rather than Toast.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comment :-

> As a side note, is there a way to click on an entry to edit the content? At any rate, absolute gold my friend, thanks again!!

Yes, pretty easy. Will modify the DiaryEntry activity to accept data according to an Entry's id (will refer to it as entryId) and to update rather than insert if Editing rather than inserting new.

- You NEED to modify DairyEntry anyway to ascertain the user for whom the Entry is being made.

However, the DatabaseHelper also needs amending. It needs to be able to Update a Diary Entry and also to retrieve the other data according to the entryId.

- I've made some other changes

  - as the JOIN will be utilised more than once I've added constants.
  - same with the columns to be extracted
  - as there is ambiguity between the 2 _id columns (USERDATE and DiaryEntry) the USERDATA column is renamed (constant for it's new name)

So **DatabaseHelper** is now :-

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /*
        Can be useful to have names available elsewhere (e.g. some are used in MainActivity)
     */
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "USER_RECORD";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USER_DATA";
    public static final String ENTRY_TABLE_NAME = "diary_entry";
    //public static final String COL_1 = "ID "; /* Cursor Adapters MUST HAVE _id column so replaced by next line */
    public static final String COL_1 = BaseColumns._ID; /* Cursor Adapter expects _id column name */
    public static final String COL_2 = "USERNAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String COL_4 = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_5 = "ENTRY";
    public static final String COl_6 = "user_map";
    public static final String DERIVED_USERID_COLUMN = "userid"; /*<<<<< ADDED used to disambiguate column names >>>>>*/


    /*<<<<< ADDED 2 constants for Join between Entry and User and for the columns >>>>>*/
    private static final String ENTRYTABLE_USERTABLE_JOIN = ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + " JOIN " + TABLE_NAME + " ON " + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + "." + COl_6 + "=" + TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_1 + " ";
    private static final String[] ENTRYTABLE_USERTABLE_COLUMNS = new String[]{
            ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + ".*",
            TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_1 + " AS " + DERIVED_USERID_COLUMN, /* give the USER _id column an alternative name using AS clause so there are not 2 _id columns */
            TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_2,
            TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_3
    };

    private SQLiteDatabase db; // saves having to use getWritableDatabase all the time */

    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Forces an open of the database
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_2 + " TEXT," +
                COL_3 + " TEXT" +
                ")"
        );
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_4 + " TEXT, " +
                COL_5 + " TEXT, " +
                COl_6 + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + /* Included for ListView */
                COL_1 +
                ") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE " +
                ")"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME); /* ADDED */
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean registerUser(String username, String password) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // no need now
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_2, username);
        values.put(COL_3, password);
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values) > 0;
        /* Simpler return used
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
         */
    }

    /* This version returns the id of the inserted user (can be useful) */
    public long otherReqisterUser(String userName, String password) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_2,userName);
        values.put(COL_3,password);
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }

    public boolean diaryEntry(Long userid, String date, String diaryText) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // not needed now
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COl_6,userid);
        values.put(COL_4, date);
        values.put(COL_5, diaryText);
        return db.insert(ENTRY_TABLE_NAME, null, values) > 0;
    }

    /*<<<<< ADDED >>>>>*/
    public long updateDiaryEntry(long entryId, String date, String entry) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_4,date);
        values.put(COL_5,entry);
        return db.update(ENTRY_TABLE_NAME,values,COL_1 + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(entryId)});
    }

    /*<<<<< ADDED >>>>>*/
    public Cursor getEntryById(long entryId) {
        return db.query(
                ENTRYTABLE_USERTABLE_JOIN,
                ENTRYTABLE_USERTABLE_COLUMNS,
                ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_1 + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(entryId)},
                null,null,null
        );
    }

    /*
    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER_DATA", null);
        return cursor;
    }
     */

    public Cursor getData() {
        /* rather than rawQuery query convenience method is recommended
           However, this one is a little complex now due to Join
         */

        /* The following is the equivalent of :-
            SELECT diary_entry.*, USER_DATA.USERNAME, USER_DATA.PASSWORD
            FROM diary_entry
            JOIN USER_DATA ON diary_entry.user_map = USER_DATA.id
            ORDER BY USER_DATA._id ASC, diary_entry.date
            ;
         */
        return db.query(
                /* Although doco says this arg is table it is actually the FROM clause so JOIN's go here*/
                /*ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + " JOIN " + TABLE_NAME + " ON " + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + "." + COl_6 + "=" + TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_1*/
                ENTRYTABLE_USERTABLE_JOIN, //<<<<< CHANGED to use constant as JOIN used elsewhere
                /* The columns as a String[] */
                ENTRYTABLE_USERTABLE_COLUMNS, //<<<<< CHANGED to use constant as columns used elsewhere
                /* no WHERE clause, no bound parameters (?), no GROUP BY clause, no HAVING clause*/
                null,null,null,null,
                /* However ORDER BY clause by user then by date */
                TABLE_NAME+"."+COL_1+" ASC," + ENTRY_TABLE_NAME + "." + COL_4 + " ASC"
                );
    }
}
```

**DiaryEntry** becomes :-

```
public class DiaryEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_USERID = "userid";
    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_ENTRYID = "entryid";

    EditText date, diaryEntry;
    Button createBtn, doneBtn;
    private DataBaseHelper myDB;
    private long entryId = -1, userId = -1;
    private String userName, password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary_entry);
        // Get the entryId (if editing entry else should be -1) AND
        // the userId (MUST BE PROVIDED if ADDING will be retrieved when editing and Entry)
        entryId = this.getIntent().getLongExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_ENTRYID,-1);
        userId = this.getIntent().getLongExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_USERID,-1);

        date = findViewById(R.id.dateField);
        diaryEntry = findViewById(R.id.entryField);
        createBtn = findViewById(R.id.diaryEntryBtn);
        doneBtn = this.findViewById(R.id.done);
        myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        // Id Entry ID provided then populate the Edit Texts
        if (entryId > 0) {
            Cursor csr = myDB.getEntryById(entryId);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                date.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COL_4)));
                diaryEntry.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COL_5)));
                userId = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.DERIVED_USERID_COLUMN));
                userName = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COL_2));
                password = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COL_3));
            }
            csr.close(); // ALWAYS close cursor when finished with them
        }
        setupButtons();
    }

    private void setupButtons() {
        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // MUST HAVE A VALID USERID IF NOT CANNOT ADD OR EDIT
                if (userId < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"UNABLE TO PROCEED - NO KNOWN USER",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (entryId > 0) {
                    myDB.updateDiaryEntry(entryId,date.getText().toString(),diaryEntry.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    myDB.diaryEntry(userId,date.getText().toString(),diaryEntry.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    private void createEntry() {
        createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String passDate = date.getText().toString();
                String passEntry = diaryEntry.getText().toString();

                //boolean var = myDB.diaryEntry(passDate, passEntry);

                if (var){
                    Toast.makeText(DiaryEntry.this, "Entry posted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DiaryEntry.this, "Posting error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

     */
}
```

- I've changed the layout to add a DONE button (although you could just edit APPLY and return). I've used the createButton for applying (adding a new Entry or Updating).
- After Insert you should probably clear the Edit Texts but the main things is showing how you can click the list to edit and also then return and the list is updated.

Obviously **MainActivity** has been changed but not that much. Instead of toasting, it constructs an Intent adds an Extra to pass the entryId and starts the DiaryEntry activity.

Main activity's `onResume` method has been overidden to refresh the ListView.

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper db;
    Cursor csr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = this.findViewById(R.id.diaryentries); /* List View from layout */
        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        /* Add data if none exists */
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db.getWritableDatabase(),DataBaseHelper.TABLE_NAME)< 1) {
            /* Add some testing users */
            long fredsId = db.otherReqisterUser("FRED", "password");
            long marysId = db.otherReqisterUser("MARY", "password");
            /* Add some diary entries */
            db.diaryEntry(fredsId, "2021-01-01", "Got up (Fred)");
            db.diaryEntry(marysId, "2021-01-01", "Got up (Mary)");
            db.diaryEntry(fredsId, "2021-01-02", "Went to work (Fred)");
            db.diaryEntry(marysId, "2021-02-02", "Was sick.(Mary)");
            db.diaryEntry(fredsId,"1999-01-01","Ooosps wasn't around!!!!");
        }

        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr = db.getData());
        setupOrRefreshListView(); // setup the ListView

    }

    private void setupOrRefreshListView() {
        csr = db.getData();
        if (sca == null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,csr,
                    new String[]{
                            DataBaseHelper.COL_4,
                            DataBaseHelper.COL_5
                    },
                    new int[]{
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            android.R.id.text2
                    },
                    0
            );
            lv.setAdapter(sca);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    /*
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                            "You clicked on Diary Entry id = " + String.valueOf(l) +
                                    " for " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COL_2)),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                     */
                    /*
                        Clicking item takes it to the modified DiaryEntry passing the
                        entryId via the Intent.
                    */
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),DiaryEntry.class);
                    intent.putExtra(DiaryEntry.INTENT_EXTRA_ENTRYID,l);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(csr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setupOrRefreshListView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(!csr.isClosed()) {
            csr.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

When started :-

[image]

Click Entry :-

[image]

Changed text to *Actually I was around* and click Apply :-

[image]

Finally Click Done :-

[image]

Comment: Holy cow, that is *exactly* what I was looking for. Reading through the modifications, this makes much more sense than what I spent most of yesterday trying to stumble through. A million more thanks, I really appreciate all the help you've provided.